# Using enum members to templatise member functions

Tags: c++, templates, enums, function-pointers

I am writing a class which can be instantiated in different modes. A simple case maybe
a meancomputer which can compute different types of means based on the mode.

The class will be instantiated by some other piece of code, and the class code will be generic through function pointers. The specific functions associated with different modes have to be defined and pointers set as per the mode.

What i have looks like this

```
    enum StatMode { EMA, SMA} ;

    class MeanComputer {
    public:
        MeanComputer ();
        MeanComputer (const MeanComputer& orig);
        virtual ~MeanComputer();
        template <StatMode> double Update (double x);
        template <StatMode> double Sample (double x);
        void Reset();
        void setFunction() { 
            if (mode == EMA ) do_calc = /*EMA mode function*/ ;
        }  
        double (MeanComputer::*do_calc)(double);

    private:
        std::vector <double> window ;
        double mean ;
        double variance ;
        StatMode mode;
    };

    template <StatMode SMA> double MeanComputer::Update(double x) {
    }


    template <StatMode EMA> double MeanComputer::Update(double x) {
    }
```

However this doesnt seem to compile and gives error
error: no matching function for call to 'MeanComputer::Update(double&)'

How do I make this work.
I understand one way is to have each such mode function defined by different names, and set 
the function pointer then. Though that seems to require too much naming, and having cleaner mode template functions seem to be more elegant and easier to understand.

UPDATE:
The method of calculating is not set at compile time, but at runtime. however for a given object of the class the mode remains the same, so setting the pointers accordingly will do it once and for all.
Also virtual base class also works, but in the actual case a lot of computation is generic,
and only some specific or small functions depend on mode. A contrived example maybe the meancomputer takes the update of some kind of coordinate object, and it takes a pair of mode types, the SMA/EMA and latitude/longitude. So one instance maybe a a longitude mean while other is a latitude mean. The full computation is same , just one reads the different member.

Comment: Why not pass the enum as a function parameter? Why does method of calculating the mean need to be set at compile-time?

Comment: @NeilKirk Because it *can* be resolved in compile time, and switch statements are ugly.

Comment: Ok , i guess I used the wrong terms. The method of calculating is not set at compile time, but at runtime. however for a given object of the class the mode remains the same. But using switch is inefficient and definitely more bug prone. Mean is just the example, there are more complicated sceanrios. Mean just seems like a simple case

Comment: This is neither elegant nor easy to understand. This seems like exactly the right place for a base class and derived classes to implement and a factory to determine which to instantiate.

Comment: @Aggieboy How sure are you of the former, and the latter is opinion.

Comment: @user3892414 I write switch statements every day without bugs, and as for inefficient, how do you know that?

Comment: @NeilKirk It is a generally accepted opinion that `switch` is ugly, but you are right that it is an opinion nonetheless.  The performance loss and scaling issues of `switch` vs other methods like OOP, function overloading, and compile-time template programming, however, is well documented and well understood.

Comment: @Aggieboy Generally accepted - by whom? What is the performance loss? Switch statements are optimized very well by the compiler. Function overloading is irrelevant here. You need to provide justification for your claims.

Comment: @NeilKirk Branches hurt processor IPC more than anything else, and that is exactly what switch statements are.  OOP replaces O(n) branches with O(2)ish loads.  On larger scales, switches are awful and unmaintainable.  I suppose I am just as obligated to spoon feed you basic tradeoffs as much as you are obligated to do a quick google search.  This is tangential to the question, so let's stop talking about this in comments.

Comment: @Aggieboy Your assumption that a switch statement must be O(n) is incorrect. When there are only a few possible cases, the switch is commonly implemented as a jump table which has constant complexity. A jump table is conceptually similar as a function lookup table, which is what you have with virtual functions. But you could have googled this instead of me spoon-feeding you. Try to be less rude in future.

Comment: @NeilKirk  One can try to write code with bugs, but given the level of similar computation, one logical error will be copied over everywhere. And ofcourse once one detects it , its easier to fix if there are not multiple classes/fucntions to edit the code.

Comment: @Aggieboy For small pieces of code inside switch case, and small cases switch does tend to be faster, but the actual scenario I am dealing with switches aren't likely to be efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template <StatMode SMA> double MeanComputer::Update(double x) {
}
```

is the wrong syntax

```
template <> double MeanComputer::Update<SMA>(double x) {
  return 7.0;
}
```

is how you specialize.

This kind of technique is rarely a good idea.

If you want the method of calculating to be determined at run time, this is entirely the wrong approach, as you need a compile-time constant to be used to determine which `Update` to call.

You could use a pure virtual base class with `template` class implementations to remove the need to `switch` outside of the factory function.

Comment: Virtual is the best way for most solutions since most solutions probably aren't solved in compile-time, but I see nothing wrong with the compile-time resolution of functions assuming that the usage of this is known.  When it is a valid method, why would it be "rarely a good idea".

Comment: @Aggieboy Because the point of compile-time resolution is speed, but often the code is more complex and less flexible as a result and there is no speed gain in practice anyway.

Comment: @aggieboy because now we have a function `Update` that is written twice (once for `SMA` once for `EMA`).  There is no shared code, so there is little to no reason for them to be `template` cousins of each other.  About the only good reason to use this technique would be because you have outer wrapping code that is `template`d on that parameter that uses this method as part of one detail: even then, you'd probably be better off writing the methods as completely normal methods, and have stub methods/traits classes that do the redirect.

Comment: @Yakk Can you elaborate on the stub traits for redirection. As i have edited the question to elabortae, the generic computation is similar in most cases, with only a few things varying depending on mode. Hence having a new class for each object seems to be an overkill (and alsomore bug prone..if there is some error in the computation). Have a look at the latitude/longitude means i described above.