# Returning templatised member function pointers based on param

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

I want to create a traits like class using templates. One solution suggested
is to partially specialize member functions and then use function pointers to refer to them.

So what I have currently looks like this

```
enum M{
    X,
    Y
};

class A {
    //member vars
    M m;

    //member funcns
    template<> foo<X> (int, int);
    template<> foo<Y> (int, int);

    typedef double (A::*xy)(int,int);
    xy goo;

    void init(){
        goo = CHOOSE(m);
    }



xy SELECT (M p){
switch(p){
case X:
  return foo<X>
}



}
```

Now I want assign value to goo (point it ot the requisite foo , depending on m. But anything I write is said to be a syntax error. Any help on how to write the CHOOSE function.
I mean its signature, and how to return the corresponding templatised function

Comment: You might want to read about [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).

Comment: XY problem perhaps? What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Oh, and actually *showing* one or two of your attempts, including the complete errors, might help as well.

Comment: Just trying to find what should be the signature and what to return inside CHOOSE. I have changed some form of CHOOSE, but everything ends with wierd huge error msgs which i cant make anything of.

Comment: For context the previous question is [Using enum members to templatise member functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25042747/using-enum-members-to-templatise-member-functions)

Comment: "partially specialize member functions". Functions cannot be partially specialized, so this is right out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I included the selection logic in the constructor:

```
#include <iostream>

enum M { X, Y };

class A
{
  M m;

  template <M> double foo(int, int);

  typedef double (A::*xy)(int,int);
  xy goo;
public:
  A(M x);

  double doit(int x, int y)
  {
    return (this->*goo)(x, y);
  }
};

template <> double A::foo<X>(int x, int y) { return x + y; }
template <> double A::foo<Y>(int x, int y) { return x * y; }

A::A(M x)
: m(x)
{
  if (m == X)
  {
    goo = &A::foo<X>;
  }
  else if (m == Y)
  {
    goo = &A::foo<Y>;
  }
  else
  {
    throw 666; // or whatever
  }

}

int main()
{
  A a(X);
  A b(Y);

  std::cout << a.doit(7, 8) << std::endl;
  std::cout << b.doit(7, 8) << std::endl;
}
```

This program prints 15 and 56 as expected.

Comment: Not exactly what i was looking for, since I actually had to built this on the design of CHOOSE. But this helped me get the signature and return type right. So accepting this. thanks